# Off resistance of analog switch 4066 pretty low?

Tags: switches, analog, cmos

I am trying to use an analog switch to switch signals between my end nodes. Before I tried in the actual circuit, I wanted to try it in a test circuit. As [4066](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_4000_series_integrated_circuits) can act as a switch for both analog and digital signals, I tried it with a very simple circuit as below.

[image]

However, the impedance between pin_1 and pin_2 is as follows.

```
#Vdd | Vss | Vctr | R12
------------------------------
0    | 0   | 0    | 1000 kohm
6    | 0   | 6    |  100  ohm
```

Now, why is the off impedance R12 so low? I expected it to be in the order of 10<sup>9</sup> ohm.

Note:

- Vctr --> Control voltage at pin 13.
- R12  --> Impedance between pin_1 and pin_2.

Comment: You need to have a resistor from pin 13 to ground in order to do this test properly - when you open circuit the switch, the pin will "float" and may give strange values for the off-resistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My databooks show an off-state leakage current of ±50 nA (max @ 25°C, typically ±0.1 nA) for both the 4016 and the 4066. With a Vcc of 6V, you could model this as a resistance of approximately 10<sup>8</sup> Ω. I don't know why the model you found has such a low value.

Comment: Thank You, at least from your answer, I understand am not doing something fundamentally wrong.

Comment: Also with all the terminals disconnected and testing the Impedance across pin_1 and pin_2 using a multimeter, it shows 890 K ohm. Weird.

Comment: If you left the control input floating, you could be getting any amount of leakage. Tie it low in order to make that measurement.

Comment: Yep, I understand that is a problem, but still, why is it the off resistance pretty low even after that?
Have got 3 of these ICs, all have the same problem.

Comment: Control input floating was the problem.
When the control input was floating, it invariably leaked half the current.
When connected to a proper low, it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

In your second line, Vdd and Vctr are 6 volts. That means the switch is on, not off. 100 ohms is the standard on resistance. The first line, with Vdd and Vctr at 0, gives the off resistance.

Dave Tweed is right - you need a pull-down resistor on pin 13.

Depending on the LEDs you're using, you may be violating the switch's ratings. If the Vf of the LEDs is 1.3 V each, and the on-resistance is 100 ohms, you'll be pulling 15 mA. The 4066 is only rated for 10 mA.

Comment: I did add a resistance 120 ohm before pin_2 calculating the current through the circuit. It was 8 mA.
So, I dont suppose it to be a problem.
And why was the question down voted?